# CreateWindowEx() inside DLL Creates a window with an odd title

Tags: c#, c++, windows, string, dll

thank you for any amount of time spent trying to answer this.

I'm trying to create a DLL that open's a window from within the DLL. I'm running the created DLL with C#. The DLL is created in VSC, and the C# code compiled with VSC#.

The window is intalized with a call to `Initalize(const char* title)` or `Initalize(string title)` in C#. Regardless of how I try to do it, the created window is created, run's, but it's title is'nt the passed string. I've tryed using `const wchar_t*`, `LPCSTR`, `LPCWSTR`, `System.String`, `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]`, `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]`. I've tryed copying the passed string into a dynamically allocated array, allocated with new/delete and malloc/free.

I'd think it was a pointer error, but what get's me the most is that `printf("passed string: %s", title)` in my C++ code prints the correct title into the console, but my window looks like:
[image: Window with non-english text]

My C++ code is:

```
// GameInterface.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "GameInterface.h"

#include <Windows.h>

      // OpenGL was origionally implimented into here, and removed to be asked on StackOverflow.

LRESULT WINAPI DLLWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

HINSTANCE   hInstance = NULL;
ATOM        wclAtom = NULL;
HWND        hWnd = NULL;
HDC         hDC = NULL;
HGLRC       hRC = NULL;
bool        running = false;

#if _DEBUG
    #include <stdio.h>
#endif

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
           DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
           LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    #if _DEBUG
        printf("GameInterface.dll::DllMain()\n");
    #endif

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            hInstance = hModule;
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            Shutdown();
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

GAMEINTERFACE_API int Initalize(const char* title)
{
    if (hWnd != NULL)
        return 0;

    #if _DEBUG
        printf("GameInterface.dll::Initalize(\"%s\")\n", title);
    #endif

    int length = strlen(title);
    char* name = new char[length+1];
    strcpy(name, title);

    WNDCLASSEXA wcl;
    wcl.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXA);
    wcl.style         = CS_OWNDC;
    wcl.lpfnWndProc   = DLLWindowProc;
    wcl.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wcl.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wcl.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wcl.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcl.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_APPWORKSPACE;
    wcl.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wcl.lpszClassName = name;
    wcl.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    wclAtom = RegisterClassExA(&wcl);

    #if _DEBUG
        printf("  Registering Class\n");
    #endif

    if (!wclAtom)
    {
        #if _DEBUG
            printf("  Error: Could not Register Class.\nExiting with error: %i\n", GetLastError() );
        #endif

        return 1;
    }

    #if _DEBUG
        printf("  Creating Window\n");
    #endif

    hWnd = CreateWindowExA(0,
                          (LPCSTR)wclAtom,
                          (LPCSTR)name,
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          512, 512,
                          NULL, NULL,
                          hInstance, NULL);

    if (hWnd == NULL)
    {
        #if _DEBUG
            printf("  Error: Window could not be created.\nExiting with error: %i\n", GetLastError() );
        #endif

        return 2;
    }

    #if _DEBUG
        printf("  Displaying Window\n");
    #endif

                // to reduce size removed the code to initalize an OpenGL 3.1 context

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    running = true;

    delete [] name;

    #if _DEBUG
        printf("Returning from GameInterface.dll::Initalize(const char*) with errors: %i\n", GetLastError() );
    #endif

    return 0;
}

GAMEINTERFACE_API void Shutdown()
{
    if (running = false)
        return;

    #if _DEBUG
        printf("GameInterface.dll::Shutdown()\n");
    #endif

    running = false;

    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    if (hRC != NULL) wglDeleteContext(hRC);
    if (hDC != NULL) ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);

    hRC = NULL;
    hDC = NULL;

    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    UnregisterClassA( (LPCSTR)wclAtom, hInstance);
    wclAtom = NULL;

    hWnd = NULL;

    running = false;
}

GAMEINTERFACE_API int Update()
{
    if ( (running == false) && (hWnd == NULL) )
        return 1;

    MSG msg;
    if ( PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) )
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if (running == false)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

GAMEINTERFACE_API void DrawFrame()
{
    // Contained some OpenGL code that has now been removed.
}

LRESULT WINAPI DLLWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            running = false;
            break;

        // handle other messages.

        default: // anything we dont handle.
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0; // just in case
}


// GameInterface.h : Outlines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#pragma once

#ifdef GAMEINTERFACE_EXPORTS
    #define GAMEINTERFACE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define GAMEINTERFACE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C"
{

GAMEINTERFACE_API int  Initalize(const char* title);
GAMEINTERFACE_API void Shutdown();
GAMEINTERFACE_API int  Update();
GAMEINTERFACE_API void DrawFrame();

};
```

And the C# code:

```
// GameInterface.cs
//

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class GameInterface
{
    const string GameInterfaceFile = "GameInterface_d.dll";

    [DllImport(GameInterfaceFile)] public extern static int  Initalize(string title);
    [DllImport(GameInterfaceFile)] public extern static void Shutdown();
    [DllImport(GameInterfaceFile)] public extern static int  Update();
    [DllImport(GameInterfaceFile)] public extern static void DrawFrame();
};


// Program.cs
//

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string title = "OpenGL Window Title";
        if (GameInterface.Initalize(title) != 0)
            return;

        while ( GameInterface.Update() == 0 )
        {
            // game logic.
            GameInterface.DrawFrame();
        }

        GameInterface.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

I'm stumped, have been for a while now.

Comment: Unicode is the first thing that I can think off. Perhaps the title is LPWSTR/LPCWSTR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you defining `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` in your C++ build?  You need to be, for the C# to talk to it like that.

In the Visual Studio properties for your C++ project, under **General**, set **Character Set** to **Use Unicode Character Set**.  Double-check that `/D "UNICODE"` and `/D "_UNICODE"` appear on the **C/C++ / Command Line** page.

(The opposite approach is to declare your exports as ANSI, but that's a poorer solution.  You should be supporting Unicode.)

Comment: You got close. Enshuring they where defined did'nt do it, but enshuring they where undefined did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This could be because the code is expecting ANSI.

What happens if you try this:

```
[DllImport(GameInterfaceFile, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)] public extern static int  Initalize(string title)
```

Comment: I still got the error. But thank's for the help! It put me on the right track.